# Issues with JSON Parsing Objects and Arrays

Tags: android, json, string, parsing

IM having issue with the following code im using to Parse JSON Objects and Arrays. Please see the following JSON data im trying to getText from and insert into TextViews. For some reason currently im getting a error that `summary` cannot be found. Please see JSONParser class for details.

Trying to parse the following URL is for the summary data.

https://api.company.com/api/systems/165756/summary?&key=e1e63de7276b04c9bb99adfd45b3a14c

Checking url in JSON validater (http://jsonlint.com/) I get the following

```
 {
  "energy_month": 31132,
  "current_power": 4210,
  "modules": 24,
  "energy_today": 14666,
  "system_id": 165756,
  "energy_week": 215504,
  "source": "microinverters",
  "energy_lifetime": 1545467,
  "summary_date": "2013-05-02T00:00:00-07:00"
 }
```

How here is the code im using to try and parse a few of these strings (energy_month) (current_power) etc. In my JSONParser.java i have to class to parse either a Array or Object. this may need to be fixed.

```
 protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(final String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
             arrfortextviews=new ArrayList<String>();
            // Using APIKEY from strings.xml
            String apikey = getString(R.string.apikey);

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            String systemID = settings.getString("systemID", "");

            //JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url2 + systemID + "/summary?&key=" + apikey);
            JSONObject json2 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl2(url2 + systemID + "/summary?&key=" + apikey);
            //for (int i = 0; i < json2.length(); i++) {
                //i = index
                try {
                    //JSONObject c = json2.getJSONObject(i);
                    //JSONObject geometry = json2.getJSONObject("summary");
                    Log.e("JSON Parser", json2 + args.toString());

                    String current_power = json2.getString(TAG_CURRENT_POWER);
                    String energy_lifetime = json2.getString(TAG_ENERGY_LIFETIME);

                    arrfortextviews.add(current_power);
                    arrfortextviews.add(energy_lifetime);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("JSON Parser", json2 + e.toString());
                }
            return arrfortextviews;

        }
```

JSONParser.class

```
   public class JSONParser {

private static final Context context = null;
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jarray = null;
static JSONArray jarray2 = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl2(String url) {

       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
          StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
          int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
          if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              builder.append(line);
            }
          } else {
            Log.e("==>", "No Response, Check Your API KEY");
            Toast.makeText(context,"Error Response, Check your API Key", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
        jarray = jobj.getJSONObject("summary");
        Log.e("JSON Parser", jobj + url.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        Log.e("JSON Parser", json + url + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jarray;

}
public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
          StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
          int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
          if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              builder.append(line);
            }
          } else {
            Log.e("==>", "No Response, Check Your API KEY");
            Toast.makeText(context,"Error Response, Check your API Key", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
        jarray2 = jobj.getJSONArray("systems");
        Log.e("JSON Parser", jarray2 + json + url.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        Log.e("JSON Parser", json + url + e.toString());
    }
    // return JSON String
    return jarray2;
   }
```

Comment: Well, for starters, I don't see a `summary` object in the JSON you pasted.

Comment: @PaulBurke so maybe its a array, i dont think it is. there will not be more than 1 summary. with the url its https://api.company.com/api/systems/systemID/summary? + "&key=APIKEY" . The summary? part of the url is what im parsing. Based on the JSON validator - i get the list of objects i can use. However i think i might be duplicating something, maybe its pulling the summary object, then looking for another summary object. Any idea?